# Best way to distribute sandboxed Mac apps to beta-testers

Tags: macos, cocoa, testing

I would like to send out beta versions of my Mac app (which solon Will be sand boxed) to testers. What's the best way to do that?

I can't use new Mac OS X server for this since I don't have an extra Mac to spare.

Normally for iOS I would use TestFlight. But how about Mac, can I use HockeyApp.com? I don't think I can upload sand boxed versions to HockeyApp, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use HockeyApp with sandboxed OS X apps. Just upload your .app.zip through the web UI or your .xcarchive with HockeyMac. HockeyApp detects the provisioning profile and asks testers do download it before the .app. You can collect the Mac UUID through HockeyApp too.

If you want to provide in-app updates, please follow this tutorial and make sure to use the Sparkle branch that supports sandboxing:
http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration/hockeyapp-for-mac-os-x#beta-distribution

Comment: Thanks! Just what I wanted to hear.